# Using the return value of Mysql stored function in IN() operator

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I have created a Mysql stored function to get all the child ids by parent id and it works fine, the return type of that function is `varchar` and it returns the child ids as string by comma separated like (`2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,7 ,8 ,9`).

When I put them in `IN()` operator, it brings the record related to first item (`2`).

Here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM department where id in(getChildDepartment(1))
```

**Note:** The `1` I put in parameter is the id of the parent department.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `IN` doesn't work with strings it works on columns. You should return `id`s of rows from `getChildDepartment`.

Comment: I did it, the numbers you see are the ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IN` doesn't accept a string of comma separated values but a list of values. The reason for returning one row is that there happens an implicit type conversion from string to integer since `id` column is likely to have an `INTEGER` data type.

Either change your returning values or go with:

```
SELECT * FROM department WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, REPLACE(getChildDepartment(1), ' ', ''));
```